# Llenar un SELECT con datos de una tabla en un modal en el archivo function.js

Tags: jquery, ajax, select, modal

Tengo un problema, no se como crear el código en mi archivo .js que dispone de un modal y requiero de un select para seleccionar un proveedor del producto y enviar los datos a la base con la cantidad, fecha, proveedor y valor de compra.
Les adjunto el código del archivo function.js

```
 $('.add_product').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var producto    = $(this).attr('product');
    var action      = 'infoProducto';

   $.ajax({
        url         : 'ajax.php',
        type        : 'POST',
        async       : true,
        data        : {action:action,producto:producto},

            success : function(response){

            if (response != 'error') {

                var info = JSON.parse(response);


                //$('#producto_id').val(info.idproducto);
                //$('.nameProducto').html(info.descripcion);

                $('.bodyModal').html('<form action="" method="post" name="form_add_product" id="form_add_product" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); sendDataProduct(); ">'+
                                    '<h1><i class="fas fa-cubes" style="font-size: 45pt;"></i> <br> Agregar Producto</h1>'+
                                    '<h2 class="nameProducto">'+info.descripcion+'</h2><br>'+
                                    '<input type="number" name="cantidad" id="txtCantidad" placeholder="Cantidad del Producto" required><br>'+
                                    '<input type="text" name="precio" id="txtPrecio" placeholder="Precio del Producto" required><br>'+
                                    '<input type="hidden" name="producto_id" id="producto_id" value="'+info.idproducto+'" required>'+
                                    '<input type="hidden" name="action" value="addProduct" required>'+
                                    '<div class="alert AlertAddProduct"></div>'+
                                    '<button type="submit" class="btn_new"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Agregar</button>'+
                                    '<a href="#" class="btn_ok closeModal" onclick="closeModal(); "><i class="fas fa-ban"></i> Cerrar</a>'+
                                '</form>');
            }
        },

            error   : function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }

   });


    $('.modal').fadeIn();
});
```

Les estaré muy agradecido si me ayudan a configurar el modal y el SELECT obtenga los datos a través del archivo ajax.php

Comment: Con este código obtengo los datos del producto en el archivo ajax.php

Comment: if ($_POST['action'] == 'infoProducto')
    {
      $producto_id = $_POST['producto'];

      $query = mysqli_query($conection,"SELECT idproducto,descripcion,cantidad,precio,codfamilia,familia FROM producto WHERE idproducto = $producto_id ");

      mysqli_close($conection);

      $result = mysqli_num_rows($query);
      if ($result > 0)
      {
        $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
        echo json_encode($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        exit;
      }
      echo 'error';
      exit;
    }

Answer (score 0):

- 1ro crea un modal y solo agragale las clases `modal` y `fade`
  para que no tengas que poner html en js
- 2do, el select debe recibir un evento change no click

  ```
  function _ajax(ruta, data) {

      var Ajax = $.ajax({
          url: ruta,
          data: {
              data: data
          },
          type: "POST"
      })
      return Ajax;

  };
  $('#select').on('change', function () {
      var cantidad= $('#inp-cantidad').val();
      var fecha= $('#inp-fecha').val();

      var data={'cantidad':cantidad,'fecha':fecha};
      var ruta = "../php/carrito.php";
      _ajax(ruta, data)
          .done(function (informacion) {
              console.log(informacion);
              var info = JSON.parse(informacion);
              $('input-modal').val(info.data[0].variable);
              $('input-modal').val(info.data[0].variable);
              $('input-modal').val(info.data[0].variable);
               $('#modalMostrar').modal('show');


          });

  });
  ```